# How to place Scrollbar in top of HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am building two HorizontalScrollViews - one on top and the other on the bottom.
  The **idea** is that:
*Top Scroll view has ScrollBar on the bottom of it.

Bottom Scroll view will have it's ScrollBar on top.*

By default ScrollBar is on the bottom. I have looked through different HorizontalScrollView properties and check what they do but none seems to control the top/bottom position. There is android:verticalScrollbarPosition, but it is not related to Horizontal ScrollBar.

Thank you!

Here is part of XML I have in the file:
LinearLayouts within HorizontalScrollViews are used to hold ImageButtons which are added / removed programmatically.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp">


    <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:id="@+id/top_pane"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:id="@+id/middle_pane"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_pane"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your xml please

Comment: @TimCastelijns - added XML to the post

Comment: have you got the solution then please share it because i have same functionality?

Comment: @Shailesh hey, I didn't find the solution. Android version incremented few times since last time I worked with this 2 years ago. Maybe they added a functionality to control this..

Comment: Still not possible, but by implementing so tricks we can do this. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660089/scrollbar-on-top-side-in-horizontal-recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

Some research suggests you can control the scrollbar style with setScrollBarStyle passing in one of the following enums;

```
SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY
SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET
SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY
SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_INSET
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollBarStyle(int) for more information.

Comment: It makes Scrollbars fade but it doesn't change ScrollBar position